# for loop in a switch-dictionary for interactive menu

Tags: python, for-loop, switch-statement

I have a problem in a SWITCH /CASE Disctionary I am trying to implement. I got an example from [here](http://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html)

I simply create an interactive menu in which you can choose more than 1 option at the same time in the order you choose them.

```
ip = ["10.10.10.1","10.10.10.2"]

def display_menu():
    os.system('clear')
    main_title = "***** MENU *****"
    print main_title.center(50,' ')
    print("\n\n\t1. Ping Check\n\t2. CPU Load.")

#Allows you to choose more than one option
def pick_the_order():
    display_menu()
    order = map(int,raw_input("Choose (separated by spaces if more than one): ").split())
    return order
```

Once it chooses the options it calls the proper functions:

```
def echo_pick(ips1):
  print "ECHO call", ips1

def snmp_pick(ips1):
  print "SNMP Call", ips1

def numbers_to_functions_to_strings(argument):
  global ip    
  for ips, option in zip(ip, argument):
    print "Ip:",ips
    print "option:", option
    switcher = {
        1: echo_pick(ips),
        2: snmp_pick(ips)
    }
    switcher.get(option, "That is not a valid option")

print numbers_to_functions_to_strings(pick_the_order())
```

The problem I am facing is that, when running the program it runs the for for each of the options, no matter if your option is 1 or 2. The output is something like this (when choosing option 1 and 2):

```
Ip: 10.10.10.1
option: 1
ECHO call 10.10.10.1
SNMP Call 10.10.10.1
Ip: 10.10.10.2
option: 2
ECHO call 10.10.10.2
SNMP Call 10.10.10.2
None
```

And the output I am looking for is this (when choosing option 1 and 2):

```
Ip: 10.10.10.1
option: 1
ECHO call 10.10.10.1
ECHO call 10.10.10.2
Ip: 10.10.10.2
option: 2
SNMP Call 10.10.10.1
SNMP Call 10.10.10.2
None
```

What is making the FOR going through all the options? Even when I choose only 1 option, say ECHO call, it should only call `echo_pick(ips1)`, but it still calls `snmp_pick(ips)`

Can anybody can help me on what part of my logic is not working properly? It seems that is is bypassing the values in option and just runs them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually make the function call, and not use the reference to those functions.

If you define your dictionary as following:

```
switcher = {
    1: func1(ips)
    2: func2(ips)
}
```

You already made the call to `func1` and `func2`. The solution here is just to make a reference to those functions, get the right one and execute it:

```
def numbers_to_functions_to_strings(argument):
    # global ip: no need to make it global since you do not modify them.

    switcher = {
        1: echo_pick,  # <-- reference to the function
        2: snmp_pick
    }

    for option in arguments:
        if option not in swticher:
            print("Invalid option:", option)
            continue

        func_to_call = switcher[option]  # <-- pick the right function
        for ips in ip:  # NOTE: you should reverse ips and ip. Naming convention :)
            func_to_call(ips)  # <-- call the function
```

Note that I didn't zip the arguments. Maybe it is because I didn't understand the problem but I think that you misuse the `zip` function here.

Comment: FunkySayu, thanks for the reply. It works just fine, you are great. 
Also It would be word mentioning that the main issue I had is that instead a print I was supposed to use RETURN, that was one of the problems.
As for the ZIP, I left it because the original code in the for I use it to get into many arrays and run it consecutively for comparison and matching reasons.

Comment: Also to mention that your solution helped me with a performance problem I was getting while applying it in a different way. Thanks

Comment: Well I guess you can store the return values inside a list, and fill the list at each function call. Do you want to pick all the results ? What is the expected return formating ? It is not really clear in your problem :)

Comment: For the functions `X_pick` inside of them I call other functions that call an echo request and an SNMP get that I also use in other code. I just put the print as an example, but I realized that was one of the problems. But mainly the SWITCH/Case you build up there helped me to call them properly and also it helped me to improve the performance of the call (it calls them faster).
The return values are only boolean values so I can use them for other decisions in the main program.